# Looking for solution how to exit the loop at the right place

Tags: c#, robotics

Okay guys so first I want to find three freePositions, one is sortedSystem.BooleanCellSystem[row][column] and than go back and change the row, my question is where I should put {break;} So I can Have 3 freePosition with different row. Thank you :)

```
public void FindingFreeCells(SortingSystem sortedSystem, int number)
{
  int freePositions = 0;
  double tempCoef = 0;

  for (int row = 0; row < sortedSystem.BooleanCellSystem.Length; row++)
  {
    for (int column = 0; column < sortedSystem.BooleanCellSystem[row].Length; column++)
    {
      if (sortedSystem.BooleanCellSystem[row][column] != true)
      {
        for (int n = column; n < number; n++)
        {
          if (sortedSystem.BooleanCellSystem[row][column] == true)
          {
            break;
          }
          for (int k = 1; k < 3; k++)
          {
            if (sortedSystem.BooleanCellSystem[row][column + k] != true)
            {
              tempCoef += 5;
            }
          }
          if (n == number - 1)
          {
            freePositions++;
            AvailableCell temp = new AvailableCell();
            temp.FirstRow = row;
            temp.FirstColumn = column;
            temp.CellsRequired = number;
            temp.PriorityCoeff = row + column + tempCoef;
            AvailableCellsList.Add(temp);
          }
        }
      }               
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to "break": This will sooner or later end in an IndexOutOfBoundsException because column+k may be higher than that dimension's length.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to find free cells in a jagged Array that has 28 rows and 210 columns. So they give me number 4, I'm checking first 4 available spots, but if there is any free space next to that spots, that is not the best match, so I need to find exactly 3 freePositions and choose the best one.

Comment: So, lets say a "spot" is 3 adjascend cells (next to each other on the same row) that are "false" , right? You need to find `number` amount of those in a matrix. And the resulting spots should not be sequential (next to each other). Is that right?

Comment: I didn't understand that "And the resulting spots should not be sequential (next to each other). Is that right?" … We should find 3 false's for sure, but after that and we add them to the list no matter what, but after that we check if there are any other 'false' next to it, if there are any more the tempCoef raises, but this is just to calculate the best coef. Anyway I need to find one best place 3 times but on different rows not only on one row.

Comment: By the way, as is, the `break` is unreachable. If the condition your outer "if" resolves to true, the inner "if" won't. Always.

Comment: Ok, this is pretty convoluted. I also do not understand, what's your assessment of "best". However, I suggest you go for a divide-and-conquer: 1. Find the longest sequence of "false" cells in each row. 2. Pick your Top 3, 3. Choose "spots" in those.

Comment: Can you help with the implementation of that structure, how it should looks.

Comment: You really need to split this code up into seperate functions that you can easily reason about. This code looks like a bunch of rope designed to hang yourself.  You're 4-levels deep on For loops!